# BlueFury BF1 and Mac OS X

Tags: asic, cgminer, bfgminer

I've been mining with ASIC miners for a short while on Mac OS X and recently bought a few BlueFury BF1 miners but no matter what I can't get them to work.

bfgminer 3.3.0 states:

/dev/cu.usbmodem1d11 is already in use by another process

And bitminter and cgminer do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bfgminer or the FPGA/ASIC window in MacMiner without removing parts of Mac OS

http://fabulouspanda.co.uk/macminer/

you can download just bfgminer and/or cgminer compiled for Mac OS X here:

http://fabulouspanda.co.uk/commandline/

Then you won't have to kextunload every time you restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working on my mac (OS X 10.9.0 Mavericks) using http://spaceman.ca/cgminer, but first steps first. Open Terminal and enter:

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCACMData
```

It will ask you for your admin password. It won't ask you for the second line (since you just recently entered your password it doesn't need it again for a few minutes).

Then open my cgminer app and enter this into the box:

```
-o poolname:portnumber -u username -p password
```